# Can I use an iPhone 6 just for the wifi?

Tags: iphone

I want to use an old iPhone 6 for my grandson to play games and get on the internet with it.  when I turn it on it goes through the start up til i get to the part about the sim card and then I can't go any further.  I don't want to activate the phone I just want to let him play his games on it.  Is this possible?  I've looked up how to do this online and I read that it can be done but some of directions on how to do it are vague.

Comment: Can you post some of the instructions you followed so we can get on the same page?

Comment: @IconDaemon It says iPhone 6

Answer (score 1):

Getting past the SIM card restriction can be done only if the iPhone 6 has been upgraded to iOS 12. Use these [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212186) instructions on how to update through the iTunes app using a USB cable connected to a computer, either Mac (preferable) or [Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210384). *Note*: iOS 12 is the last available version for the iPhone 6.

Once upgraded to iOS 12, you can then [activate your iPhone 6](https://www.wootechy.com/activation-bypass/how-to-activate-an-iphone-without-sim/) without the SIM.